# PHP express checkout digital goods issue

Tags: php, apache, curl, paypal, cpanel

This is our server info:
Apache version
WAS Apache 2.2.26
NOW IS Apache 2.4.7

PHP version
WAS 5.3.28
NOW IS 5.4.25

Our application (php) is a bit more complicated to explain but bottom line is that before the Apache + php update it was working correctly (testing in sandbox).

After the update it no longer works when trying to pay for items.
Is it possible that Paypal api requires some server "config" settings that the new apache/php might not have ?

we looked over the changelog from apache/php and don`t see any major change that can impact our communication. I believe the request to paypal from our code is made using cUrl.

From what i tried to debug it looks like the response from paypal is empty and thats why our application is throwing us the error.

Any ideas what might be preventing paypal -> server comunication since the update ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to see exactly what you're getting back in the curl response, for sure, and you can also check [curl_error](https://www.php.net/curl_error) to see if you get any useful detail there.